# Determine for which values of a is the matrix A(a) invertible?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a $4\times 4$ matrix and I am supposed to find for which values of $a$ is the matrix $A(a)$ invertible?
The matrix is as follows:
$$
A(a) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried Cramer's rule by expanding through the second column because it has three zeros in it, which made it easier. After solving I got:

$3[5a-5a^2] \implies 15a-15a^2$

How am I supposed to go further now? how can I find the values of $a$ from here?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What you need to know in addition is that $A(a)$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A(a))\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : For which $a$ do we have $15a-15a^2=15a(1-a)=0$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you want to ask?

Comment: You have to determine the values $a$, for which the determinant is $\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

The method is certainly sound. The determinant is indeed
$$
\det A(a)=3\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & a \\
0 & a & 0 \\
5 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
=3a\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
5 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
=3a(5-5a)
$$
which is different from zero if and only if $a\ne 0$ and $a\ne 1$.

Comment: is this what my answer is supposed to be? 
3a(5-5a)?
How would I right the final answer? can you please tell me?

Comment: @MuhammadQureshi The determinant is $3a(5-5a)=15a(1-a)=15a-15a^2$ (any expression is good). You want to find where the determinant is nonzero, though, not the determinant itself.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot :)